# How do you send an alt0189 to autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

In word and other programs when you hold down the alt key and type 0189 on the number keyboard you will get the half inch symbol ½. How can I send this sequence in autohotkey using a hot key

Thanks in advance
Tim

Comment: Please provide feedback on the proposed solution. When the answer was helpful, please "Accept" the answer by clicking on the WHITE "Check-mark" next to the answer, to turn it GREEN. Thank you! Clicking the check-mark will give credits to the person who submitted the answer and will mark the question as answered. See: [Accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/210367)

Comment: Tim, Could you please provide some feedback?

Answer (score 1):

In general: Send, {ASC 00189}

I do it this way:

```
; ================================== FRACTIONS ==================================
^2::
    Send, ½
    TrayTip, For 2 Squared,press Ctrl + Shift 2,1,1
Return

^3::
    Send, ¾
    TrayTip, For 3 Cubed,press Ctrl + Shift 3,1,1
Return

^4::Send, ¼

; ==================================  POWERS ==================================
+^0::Send, °
+^1::Send, ¹
+^2::Send, ² ; Shift Control 2@
+^3::Send, ³ ; Shift Control 3#
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+2 = ½
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+3 = ¾
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+4 = ¼
<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + 0 = °
<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + 1 = ¹
<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + 2 = ²
<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + 3 = ³